# Angular Measure each watcher's performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I have an application without much watchers 900~ but it still runs kind of slowly, I suspect some of my watchers include a pricy "for" loop (I eliminated most of them but I suspect some still exist)

Where do I need to altar my angular.js file so that I can wrap each watcher's run with the javascript's "performance" library and it will log the top 10 slowest watchers

Comment: You have **900** active listeners? Wow. Is this pretty typical for larger Angular apps?

Comment: Well im using ui-grid, it uses a ton of watchers, my app is 300~ it adds another 600 after I edited a ton of their code to reduce watchers

Comment: Are you unregistering watchers when the scope is destroyed?

Comment: It automatically does that, I have a loop that counts the number of watchers every 2 seconds so "Watchers Leak" is not a problem